# Jmeter 2.13 Backend Listener

Tags: jmeter, graphite, grafana

i have working with Jmeter 2.13 and try a new listener Backend listener, I'm using windows.

I have installed grafana/graphite in windows and run it from the web page
http:/localhost:8080 and run smoothly. Grafana shows standard dashboard "shared dashboards" and 'dashboards'.

In jmeter a listener Backend listers was added and configured as default
as in picture

[image]

In grafana i add a new data source:

- Name=jmeter
- Type=Graphite
- url= http://localhost:2003
- access:proxy/direct ( i tested both)
- Basic auth: (no)

When i run test in jmeter with Backend listener nothing is shown in grafana.
What did i miss, that jmeter results are not displaing [image: http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/grafana_dashboard.png]

Thank you for help,
Dani

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using InfluxDB as your backend time series database, use the below configuration in Grafana's config.js file.

```
  datasources: {
    influxdb: {
      type: 'influxdb',
      url: "http://localhost:8086/db/jmeter",
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
    },
    grafana: {
      type: 'influxdb',
      url: "http://localhost:8086/db/grafana",
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      grafanaDB: true
    },
  },
```

Also make sure that your InfluxDB server is up and running by checking "http://localhost:8086". It should show you the login page to connect to the influxdb's web console.

Lastly, enable "DEBUG" logging in JMeter in the jmeter.properties file(log_level.jmeter=DEBUG) and share more info about the errors you see in the log if the issue still persists.

Comment: Hi, i wasn't able to find config.js in grafana 2.02 ii found only c:\apps\grafana-2.0.2\public\app\components\require.config.js, i made a change and no effect was done when i started grafana ( run grafana.exe)

Comment: this was in grafana 1.0, which seems is no longer a possibility in 2.0